# How is memory usage calculated in Task Manager in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager

This is a screenshot of Task Manager of Windows 10 on my laptop (Intel Haswell Core i7, 16 GB RAM). It shows **3.6 GB** on the left side, but on the right side none of the values read **3.6 GB**. I can only find the graph equal to that value, with each horizontal line indicating 10% of total RAM (1.6 GB) and the graph slightly above the 2nd line (3.2 GB).

> [image: hahaha]

Where does the **3.6 GB** on the left side come from?

Comment: Can you submit a screenshot of RAMMAP to get a better understanding of your memory usage?  It would help to know which build of Windows 10 you are using.  In order to provide that information, use `winver`, and provide the build information.  Of course, my RAMMAP matches my memory usage within Task Manager so, but RAMMAP will better outline the usage for you.

Comment: I'll bet Resource Monitor will explain this. Click that "open resource monitor" link in the task manager screen you copied and then go to the Memory tab.